# nfc-event deamon: read URL from nfc-tag instead of just UID

Tags: python, nfc

It is quite hard to find a community for nfc-eventd since the official forum is down. I hope I am right asking my question here. I am currently trying to parse an URL from an NFC tag with the deamon nfc-eventd (https://github.com/nfc-tools/nfc-eventd). The deamon has two forms of executing commands once a nbc-tag was recognized:

`nem_execute simply launches a command line specified in nfc-eventd configuration file on event. With this NEM, you can easily do many simple application, like launching particular action depending on card you put on NFC device, etc.`

`nem_dbus pushes events on D-Bus's system bus. That allow to have more than one application that handle event and manage privileges with D-Bus options.`

While nem-execute is coming with an example config, the possibilities seem quite limited. The only information provided by nem-execute is the nbc-tag UID, but no further tag information. In my case, I want to read an URL from the nfc-tag and process the information further.

Currently I am hardcoding the URLS in a list, which is filtered by a python script with the tag UID. This requires to change the list each time I wanna change an URL.

I am open to use another deamon, if there is an alternative coming with this functionality and working with the PN532 chip and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: If you want to process the information in Python you could maybe use the nfcpy library (http://nfcpy.org).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about nfcpy. It looks promising, I'll give it a try!